# Modified .htaccess to hide index.php for a routing engine cause to 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes

I've created a custom simple routing engine which works base on paths in 'PATH_INFO' in `$_SERVER`. If the rout matches with any predefined routs, it will call its controller action; otherwise it will redirect to the home page.

```
$path = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
if (in_array($path, $routs)) {
   call_user_func(array($this, $action));// $action is calculated
}
else {
   header('location: ./en');
   exit();
}
```

In this case I modified the .htaccess file as below to hide the index.php and my urls be like *http://www.example.com/en* or *http://www.example.com/en/home*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I deployed sources to my domain by hitting url *http://www.example.com* redirects to *http://www.example.com/en* which is correct; but in response for that redirect it returns a **404 Page not found** page!
Everything works fine in my machine localhost but on the web it does not work. The only different on my machine is that in .htaccess RewriteBase is set to my project path as `RewriteBase /myrouting/`.

If I go to *http://www.example.com/index.php/en* on the web it works fine; but I don't want the index.php be visible.

**UPDATE**
I changed my .htaccess as below; now if I hit *www.example.com/index.php/en* it redirects to *www.example.com/en* but still with 404 error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^index\.php)^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php(/[^\s\?]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L]
```

I will be thankful if anybody could help me what I've done wrong. I did search and tried different changes on .htaccess with no success.

Comment: Did you enable the apache mod_rewrite module on the server, and restart apache? If you have, you can enable rewrite logging to see what happens.

Comment: @skroczek I don't have access through cpanel, Or I don't know how to enable it in cPanel

Comment: Hmmm, i never used cpanel, sorry, i can't help.

Comment: @skroczek No problem I will find a way, thanks

Comment: You can always put a temporary redirect in there to check if rule is working. `[R=302,QSA,L]`. If it redirects then you know it's reading the rule.

Comment: Actually, your rule redirects 'http://www.example.com' to 'http://www.example.com/index.php/' and 'http://www.example.com/en' to 'http://www.example.com/index.php/en'. Neither looks like what you would want because of the slash after index.php (unless you have a directory index.php).

Comment: What happens if you change the rule to `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`?

Comment: @PanamaJack Thanks, when I put `[R=302,QSA,L]` and hit *example.com* it redirects to *example.com/index.php/en* which means it's enabled

Comment: @bobdye I guess you're right because if I put `[R=302,QSA,L]` it redirects to the way you mentioned; but I don't have directory called *index.php* I just want `example.com` be redirected to `example.com/en` without index.php

Comment: @MikeAnthony If I change my rule the way you mentioned it comes up with redirect loop error

Comment: @Javad  Why are you trying to do the redirect in PHP? To not confuse things. I would do the redirects all with htaccess. You can redirect from `example.com` to `example.com/en` in htaccess easily.

Comment: @PanamaJack Thanks, I don't have enough knowledge about htaccess; to me it just look like it does not hide index.php

Comment: Are you getting apache 404 error or 404 error from your application?

Comment: @PanamaJack It's http 404 page not found. On chrome or FF it says "No input file specified." and in their console I see 404 page not found error